# List last n changes in whole svn repository

Tags: svn

Theres a couple of question with nearly the same title as mine, but mine is still different...

I have a svn repository with directory structure like this:

```
.svn
/some/dir/here/a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

EDIT: My svn version is "version 1.8.10 (r1615264)"

If I have changes to a.txt and commit them and then do plain

```
$ svn log | less -S
```

in the directory where the .svn file resides or in /some/dir/here/ directory the commit does not show up. Only if I explicitly do

```
$ svn log a.txt
```

then I also see the commits to a.txt. Is this common behavior? How would I be able to see the list of the last n commits from the whole repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always say:

`svn log --limit 5 [REPO_URL]`

Take the URL to repo without any internal repository path, then you see all 
commits

*Further Explanation*: 
by using the repo_url, you are directly pointing to the root of your repository. If you use the working copy path, SVN will examine your working copy and will use the URL your Working copy is pointing to. As this is most probably not the root of your  repository you will not see the commits on other paths.